# Send text file in JSON format to AWS Lambda function

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to provide a text file as input to an AWS Lambda function. Is the only way to do this is to put the file data as a value for a name/value pair? Such as:

{
"filename": "myfile.txt",
"filedata": "This is the text in the text file"
}

Are there any other options? Thank you.

Comment: Send it how?  Via the AWS CLI?  Via a program using an AWS SDK?  With or without API gateway in the front?

Comment: Through the AWS Management Console.

Comment: No, not in the AWS console.  You can put an API Gateway in front and do an HTML form post but the console only allows JSON.

Comment: The Lambda management console has a 'Test' feature that allows you to provide data that will be sent to the function as the `event`. It won't accept a file, but you can paste the JSON into the console. This, of course, is only useful for testing and is not how you would normally invoke an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: You could put the file on s3 and only pass the file name to the lambda (for example via eventbridge). Then grant the lambda the necessary permissions to retrieve it from there.

Comment: I am using the Lambda function to upload the file to S3 so first putting the file on another S3 bucket wouldn't be the best option for me I think. I was looking into Amazon EFS, would this be an option as well?